# How to upload file using window dialog box in Robot Framework?

Tags: selenium, file-upload, automation, robotframework, dropzone.js

In my application I have a dropzone(Which is not having input type = file) where I can upload files using window dialog box. But using Choose File Keyword, I am not able to upload file, because which is not pointing to .

Below is the xpath for that element,

```
//*[@id="scroller"]/div[3]/xyz-dropzone
```

Can someone please help me to solve this ? Do we have any keyword to upload file for dropzone ?

I have tried below which is not working,

```
Choose File    //*[@id='scroller']/div[3]/xyz-dropzone    C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\Skype issue.png./
```

Getting below error,

```
"Element not interacted".
```

Below is the html source code(polymer) for that element,

```
<xyz-dropzone piid="{{piid}}" config="{{config}}" endpoint="/file-upload" dzid="photos" maxfiles="{{maxfiles}}" imageTemplate="{{dropzoneTemplate}}" attachments="{{attachmentsload}}"></xyz-dropzone>
```

Comment: can you post the html source & complete stack trace for the error.

Comment: HI Sureshmani,
Below is the html source code(polymer) for that element,
<xyz-dropzone piid="{{piid}}" config="{{config}}" endpoint="/file-upload" dzid="photos" maxfiles="{{maxfiles}}" imageTemplate="{{dropzoneTemplate}}" attachments="{{attachmentsload}}"></xyz-dropzone>

And below is the error shown in Robot,
ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable

Comment: Somewhere on that page has to be an `<input>` field. Are you absolutely certain that there isn't a hidden `<input>` field in the body of the document?

Comment: Hi @BryanOakley,
The field is drag and drop zone field. But we can add file in 2 ways. 
1. Using drag and drop
2. Upload file using dialog box
If I use method 1(Drag and Drop) we don't have <input> field.
If I use method 2 (Upload file) Before uploading file, We don't have any <input>  field. But we have it in the html  source only after uploaded the file. Please find the below source code which I got after uploaded file .
<input type="file" class="dz-hidden-input" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.png" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; height: 0px; width: 0px;">

Comment: try sending path of file to that input tag using send keys

Comment: @Dev,
I don't have input tag in my source code. It is based on polymer application. Not html. Will be able to send path without input tag ?